# Customized JBoss Configuration or Deployment Folder

Tags: eclipse, jboss, war

I want to create a separate configuration in JBoss Application Server . Adding to this I want to add a folder which will be project folder of web application created through eclipse. The main idea is to create a separate deploy folder which contains files like resources, WAR's etc related to particular application only.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the main reason or want to achieve with this?

Comment: to reduce build time in development environment, also to study various options for production deployment

Answer (score 0):

Production deployment should be done using only EARs (or WARs). That's the standard way of deploying Java EE applications. Most Application Servers allows you to add other resources to an EAR, which is the descriptor for that specific AS. So, target for having a single EAR file for deploying your application.

But for development, that might make sense. Actually, you can use JBoss Tools, configure your JBoss AS on it and add an Eclipse project to this server. Any changes you make will be automatically deployed.

But you can certainly create a profile by your own, with only the things you need from the AS. To do that, I simply copy the profile that is closest to what you want to achieve and start changing from there. For instance, you can copy the "minimal" profile and start adding the services you need, calling it "myprofile". Then you can just start JBoss AS with "./run.sh -c myprofile".